# Comparing two list by using Java8 Matching Methods

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using Java8 matching methods am able to compare two list and getting the boolean results when if the is any match is available in both the lists.

Please find my below code for that.

```
public class StreamTest2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Integer> aList = Arrays.asList( new Integer[] {
                1,3,5,6,8
        });

        List<Integer> bList = Arrays.asList( new Integer[] {
                10, 89, 8, 9
        });

        //If any number in List1 present in List2
        System.out.println("If any number present in aList is present in bList : "+aList.stream().anyMatch(num -> bList.contains(num)));

    }

}
```

Output :

```
If any number present in aList is present in bList : true
```

But, i want to print the matching number from both the list, how i can print the matching number ?

Comment: Why not just `aList.retainAll(bList)`?

Comment: @LuCio - It throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` Exception

Comment: Yes, but only because you're using `Arrays.asList(...)`. Initialize the lists like that `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 6, 8));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `findFirst`:

```
System.out.println("If any number present in aList is present in bList : "+aList.stream().filter(num -> bList.contains(num)).findFirst().orElse(null));
```

This will print the matching number if found (it will stop at the first match), or `null`, if no match is found.

Or, you can collect all the matches into a `List`:

```
System.out.println("If any number present in aList is present in bList : "+aList.stream().filter(num -> bList.contains(num)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Prefect, its working as per your note. But, if there is multiple matches means how we can print all the matches.?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Instead of terminating the stream pipeline with `.findFirst()`, you can collect it to a List (`.collect(Collectors.toList()`) which will contain all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
aList.stream().filter(bList::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: why not Collectors.toSet()? @Hadi

Answer (score 1):

The reason because of which you get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` when you call `retainAll` is that `Arrays#asList` returns an ArrayList backed by an array of fixed size. Any attempt to remove or add an element to these lists will result in the aforementioned `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The solution is, as @LuCio has suggested, to wrap the `Arrays.asList` part with a ArraysList constructor call, as such:

```
List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,3,5,6,8));
List<Integer> bList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(10, 89, 8, 9));
```

the you should be able to call:

```
aList.retainAll(bList);
```

Keep in mind that this will modify the original `aList` list. If you need to preserve the state of `aList` then I would suggest to make a copy of `aList` before invoking `retainAll`. One of the suggested Stream API approached would in this case maybe be more suitable.